# Craps Simulator Exercise

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, simulation

I did another exercise, this time it simulates n games of craps(dice game) and outputs the wins and win percentage!

```
#craps.py -- Simulates multiple games of craps
#   and estimates the probability that the player wins.

import random

def output(wins, total):
    winrate = wins / total
    print("The player won {0} of {1} games ({2:0.2%})".format(wins, total, winrate))

def rolldies():
    dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll = dice1 + dice2
    return roll

def simOneGame():
    initial_roll = rolldies()
    if initial_roll == 2 or initial_roll == 3 or initial_roll == 12:
        return True     # won
    elif initial_roll == 7 or initial_roll == 11:
        return False    #lost
    else:
        #Roll until roll is 7 or initial roll
        roll = rolldies()
        while roll != 7 and roll != initial_roll:
            roll = rolldies()
        if roll == 7:
            return True     #won
        else:
            #roll is inital_roll
            return False    #lost

def simNGames(games_to_sim):
    wins = 0
    for i in range(games_to_sim):
        if simOneGame():
            wins += 1
    return wins

def main():
    games_to_sim = int(input("How many games to simulate? "))
    wins = simNGames(games_to_sim)
    output(wins, games_to_sim)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Always open for suggestions on what to improve/do differently or more pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

First, Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which programmers are encouraged to follow. This makes it easier for other Python programmers to read your code. PEP8 recommends using `lower_case` both for variable and function names, which I have used in the code below.

In your `output` function you use string formatting (good). However note that if you just want to paste the values in order, there is no need to explicitly mention the indices. So you could write `"The player won {} of {} games ({:0.2%})".format(wins, total, winrate)`. But there is an even easier way in [Python 3.6+: f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498). I also think this is not enough to put it into a function, I would just leave it as a single line in `main`:

```
print(f"The player won {wins} of {total} games ({wins/total:0.2%})")
```

Your `rolldies` function could be made more general if it accepted a parameter telling it how many dice to roll. You can also use a list comprehension here, or [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
def roll_dice(n=2):
    return sum(random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n))

DIE = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
def roll_dice(n=2):
    return sum(random.choices(DIE, k=n))
```

Note that the singular is "die" and the plural is "dice", not "dies".

In your `simOneGame` function, instead of chaining a lot of comparisons with `or`, just use `in`:

```
def sim_game():
    initial_roll = roll_dice()
    if initial_roll in {2, 3, 12}:
        return True     # won
    elif initial_roll in {7, 11}:
        return False    # lost
```

Your rolling in the `else` branch can also be a bit shortened:

```
    else:
        #Roll until roll is 7 or initial roll
        roll = roll_dice()
        while roll not in {7, initial_roll}:
            roll = roll_dice()
        return roll == 7    # 7 wins
```

You could theoretically replace the `while` loop with a single `random.choices` call, but you would have to manually set the probabilities to the right values.

The `simNGames` function can be shortened a lot by using the fact that `False == 0` and `True == 1`:

```
def sim_n_games(n):
    return sum(sim_game() for _ in range(n))
```

Comment: What is the difference between "in (2,3,12)" and "in {2,3,12}" ?

Comment: @Meph-: The first one is a `tuple` and the latter one a `set`. For small collections there will be basically no difference, but a `set` has `O(1)` membership testing, while a `tuple` is slightly faster to construct, but has `O(n)` membership testing. On my machine `1 in (2, 3, 12)` takes 53.9 ns ± 0.361 ns and `1 in {2, 3, 12}` takes 55.2 ns ± 2.07 ns.

Comment: @Meph-: And for completeness sake (and to show that it is better than chaining `or`), `1 == 2 or 1 == 3 or 1 == 12` takes 73.3 ns ± 0.658 ns.

Comment: I'll put the formatting changes to use! Thanks. As to using "in", i simply havent learned that yet(tuples, sets),it will probably come later in my programming book, but I'll implement it right away. Really seems to be the better choice. Sorry for the die/dice mixup haha.

Comment: Okay, it seems like
`print(f"The player won {wins} of {total} games ({wins/total:0.2%})")` doesn't work. i think you can't calculate anything in there

Comment: @Kevin: No, it should work. You can use arbitrary Python expressions inside f-strings (and even some subset of Python expressions like attribute and item access in the format string you are using).

Comment: @Graipher it recognizes the `:` in `{wins/total:0.02}` as the end of the whole statement in the brackets, not sure why. Everything after and including the `:` is seen as string

Comment: @Kevin: Well, I just copy & pasted it (from your comment), just to be sure, with `wins, total =  10, 23` and it works on my machine.

Comment: @Kevin: Maybe you are missing the `%`? You either need that or a `:0.2f`.

Comment: @Graipher Here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/nMUsSFY

Comment: @Kevin: Looks fine to me? It even correctly colors the expression part. Have you tried running that line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89969/discussion-between-graipher-and-kevin).

Comment: @Graipher It prints `The player won 100 of 200 games (0.5)`. What throws me off is that the last `}` isn't in red, but in green, indicating it's part of the string.